# TextMesh support for LTR languages in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, right-to-left

I am working on a Hebrew word game in Unity.

My problem is with displaying Hebrew text inside textMesh object. I need to reverse my words in order to write / read them correctly as Hebrew is a right to left languages.

Is there a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never used it, but there's a plugin on GitHub exactly for that (RTL Text Mesh Pro): https://github.com/mnarimani/RTLTMPro

[image]

Comment: It's built in TMP already, there is checkbox like "enable RTL editor"